# Manipulate constraint to move a view to the bottom of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nslayoutconstraint

I have a collection view that is aligned horizontally and vertically in the container. When a user selects the cell I want that collection view to move to the bottom of the screen, and then I want a UIView to appear right above the collection view.

Below is how my collection view is constrained.
[image: constrains]

So the way I went about this was making the bottom space constraint an outlet in my code file.

```
@IBOutlet var collectionViewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Then when a user tapped on the cell, i ran this function here

```
func showWatchView(selectedPath: Int) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.collectionViewBottomConstraint.constant = 0
        })
        clipsCollectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

However, when I tried this it moved the collection view to the top of the screen instead of the bottom of the screen, and it didn't even animate it, it just went up there.

Comment: You need to first change constraint value before animation. It immediately changed. But when you change constraints value you need to layout your view by calling self.view.layoutIfNeeded() method. If you write this method in anmation's method then it will change with animation.

Comment: It didn't work, it still just disappears and doesn't animate

Comment: `self.collectionViewBottoConstraint.constant = self.view.bounds.height - collectionView.bounds.height` animated it, however the height of the collection view has become very small. How can i fix that?

Comment: which method from you call this method ?

Comment: I call this outside of the animation block, and call layoutIfNeeded() inside the animation block

Comment: Yes, But I talk about showWatchView, this method call from viewDidLoad ?

Comment: No it is called on the didSelectItemAt: method for the collection view. I call this method when a cell in the collection view is tapped

Comment: I think mistake in your constraint. Becuase you set the collection view center vertically rather that given to top, bottom, left, right. Make your collectionView constraints proper.

Comment: Yup that fixed it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The constant needs to be set to 0

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewOutlet: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomContraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionViewOutlet.delegate = self
        collectionViewOutlet.dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        showWatchView(selectedPath: indexPath.item)
    }

    func showWatchView(selectedPath: Int) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.bottomContraint.constant = 0
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { (completed) in
            // do something
        })
    }

}
```

Since you want the collectionView to be at the bottom and self.view.layoutIfNeeded() needs to be called inside the animation with a duration of your choosing, 0.3 is ok for starters.

Comment: It didn't work, it still just disappears and doesn't animate

Comment: `self.collectionViewBottoConstraint.constant = self.view.bounds.height - collectionView.bounds.height` animated it, however the height of the collection view has become very small. How can i fix that?

Comment: Make sure you add a constraint on the height of the collection view if you want to preserve it.

Comment: And also set the duration of the animation longer, something like 0.3